# Difference between "Ich zögere nicht, ihr zu empfehlen" and "Ich zögere nicht, sie zu empfehlen"

Tags: english-to-german, difference, grammatical-case, german-to-english

1. > Ich zögere nicht, **ihr** zu empfehlen als starke Kandidatin für ein postgraduales Assistenzzeit-Programm zur Sicherstellung ihrem bemerkenswerten Erfolg in der Zukunft.
2. > Ich zögere nicht, **sie** zu empfehlen als starke Kandidatin für ein postgraduales Assistenzzeit-Programm zur Sicherstellung ihrem bemerkenswerten Erfolg in der Zukunft.

That's the translation:

> I have no hesitation in recommending her as a strong candidate for postgraduate residency program ensuring her remarkable success in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first sentence is simply wrong as it is missing a verb. This sentence would be correct if you said:

> Ich zögere nicht, ihr zu empfehlen, als starke Kandidatin für ein postgraduales Assistenzzeit-Programm zur Sicherstellung ihres bemerkenswerten Erfolges in der Zukunft **zu kandidieren**.

That would mean: you recommand to her that she should canidate for that position. It is dativ clause in that case.

Your second sentence means exactly what you wanted to say as it uses accusative form. You just need to fix the phrase "ihres bemerkenswerten Erfolges" as well, as it is wrong in both of your original sentences.

Comment: "Assistenzzeitprogramm" ein Wort.